# have foreach inside of an array?

Tags: php

I am wondering how to put a foreach inside of an array. I've tried the following

```
$service_url = 'http://api.XXXXXXX/addData';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);               
$curl_post_data = array(              
    foreach ($additional_fields as $name => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {                     
            '$name' => $value,
        }                  
);
```

but its giving me the error `unexpected T_foreach`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't have a *statement* inside an *expression*. You probably just need `$curl_post_data = array_filter($additional_fields)` though.

Comment: `how to put a foreach inside of an array` - you don't/can't.